# How do we find a file that is located some where in directory tree

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

How do we find a file that is located some where in directory tree hierarchy and was accessed 3 days ago.
Which command should we use.

**Find 
or 
Locate**

Are there any other Unix commands for this

Also
can i execute shell scripts using Alias

like

**alias p='/hosting/apps/exception.sh'**

When i use this its throwing exception saying file doesn't exist

Comment: did you really have that file? check via `ls /hosting/apps/exception.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Locate command to find files in Unix.

When you have to find files, you might typically use find command. find is a great search utility but it is slow.

However locate can search for files very quickly.
Well, locate does not search the files on disk rather it searches for file paths in a database.

```
# locate -e sysctl.conf
/etc/sysctl.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/sysctl.conf.5.gz
```

The database is a file that contains information about the files and their path on your system. The locate database file is located at:

```
/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db
```

Using find you can get what you are looking for

So to find text files that were last modified 60 days ago, use

```
 find /osting -iname "*.txt" -mtime -60 -print

-mtime +60 means you are looking for a file modified 60 days ago.
-mtime -60 means less than 60 days.
-mtime 60 If you skip + or - it means exactly 60 days.
```